# How to tell WPF Path the Canvas boundries?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am trying to draw a minus symbol, based on a canvas of 100x100, but I end up with a square, because WPF does not know how big my canvas is.  How can I tell it about the Path container size?

```
 <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckIcon"
                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Data">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <PathGeometry >
                                    <PathFigure StartPoint="20,60">
                                        <LineSegment Point="20,60"/>
                                        <LineSegment Point="80,60"/>
                                        <LineSegment Point="80,45"/>
                                        <LineSegment Point="20,45"/>
                                    </PathFigure>
                                </PathGeometry>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

Comment: Which Canvas? You only have a PathGeometry. In order to set its bounds, add some invisible segments.

Comment: @Clemens how can I make an invisible segment?  The color is set on the Path itself, so it seems like adding another segment will result an another segment of the same color as the Path color.

Comment: Create any segment (e.g. a LineSegment) with the `IsStroked` property set to false. Or create a another PathFigure with a StartPoint but an empty Segments collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was not intuitive, but Clemens helped me to get to the answer

```
<PathGeometry>
    <PathFigure>
        <LineSegment Point="0,0" IsStroked="False"/>
        <LineSegment Point="20,60" IsStroked="False"/>
        <LineSegment Point="20,60"/>
        <LineSegment Point="20,60"/>
        <LineSegment Point="80,60"/>
        <LineSegment Point="80,45"/>
        <LineSegment Point="100,100" IsStroked="False"/>
        <LineSegment Point="80,45" IsStroked="False"/>
        <LineSegment Point="20,45"/>
        <LineSegment Point="20,60"/>
    </PathFigure>
</PathGeometry>
```